# In protobuf-net, what is the code eqivalent of [ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

In protobuf-net, what is the non-attribute code equivalent of [ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]?

If the answer is out there, my search skills are failing me. I am using the most recent version of protobuf-net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, there is no MetaType API to do this - you would need to use reflection to get the fields and call Add in turn with each. Note: GetFields explicitly does not guarantee any particular order, so you should also sort the fields manually (typically alphabetically).

Comment: Thanks Marc, great job on the project BTW, it works like a charm.